# How do I register a compressor with sprockets on the command line?

Tags: ruby, debian, sprockets, terser

I want to use Sprockets at the command line (with the ruby-sprockets Debian package), and I want to use Terser as the JavaScript compressor (because Uglify doesn't support ES6). All the documentation I've seen suggests that I can create a file with the following code:

```
require 'sprockets'
require 'terser'

Sprockets.register_compressor 'application/javascript', :terser, Terser::Compressor
```

to register Terser with Sprockets, and then I tack on a `--require FILE` to my call to `sprockets` at the command line. I know it's processing the script, because I can add something like this to the file:

```
Sprockets.js_compressor = :terser
puts Sprockets.js_compressor
```

and it prints `Terser::Compressor` as one might expect.

HOWEVER. When I run sprockets with something similar to this:

```
sprockets  --require ./register_compressor.rb  --js-compressor=terser ...
```

I get the response:

```
/usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/sprockets/compressing.rb:63:in `js_compressor=': 
unknown compressor: terser (Sprockets::Error)
```

I've been banging my head against this problem for way too long.

Answer (score 2):

Ok, so for the next person who runs into this (apparently very rare) problem, you need to patch `Sprockets::Environment.js_compressor=`:

```
module Sprockets
  class Environment < Base
    def js_compressor=(compressor)
      register_compressor 'application/javascript', :terser, Terser::Compressor
      super
    end
  end
end
```

Comment: Not that uncommon @crunchytacogal, I also ran into it. As far as I can tell, unlike the other compressors defined as supported by Sprockets (like Uglifier and Sass), they actually have loaders defined in the library whereas Terser does not.